# I'm applying the same methods to multiple dataframes in spark scala, how can I parallelize this?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi how's it going? I'm currently looping through all of my dataframes and running essentially the same queries/filters on them. Would there be a way to run this more effectively, in parallel? Here's sample code...

```
    for (db <- list_of_dbs)
    {


      var df1 = spark.read
        .format("csv")
        .option("sep",",")
        .option("inferSchema","true")
        .option("header","true")
        .load(path+db+".csv")
        .withColumn("name_of_data",lit(db))


      if (db!="rules") {


        val conversion = mappingDF
          .filter(col("col1").isNotNull and col("name") === db) 

      }
```

etc etc...

Is there a way so that this can be run on all dataframes at once, essentially getting rid of the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

you can union all your dataframe than apply the filter/querys to it:

[https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#unionByName(other:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#unionByName(other:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D)

you can also use csv method of DatasetReader to load multiple csv in same time (recommended) :

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#csv(paths:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame